# Maven2 AAR Eclipse plugin not adding services.xml to aar

Tags: maven-2, eclipse-plugin, apache-axis

Maven gurus, please help a newbie here:

My POM looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.pidac.webservices</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis2test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Axis2-test</name>

   <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-aar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>axis2-aar:aar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                             
                            <fileSets>
                                <fileSet>
                                     <directory>${project.build.directory}/aar</directory>
                                     <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                                </fileSet>
                                <fileSet>
                                    <directory>$(basedir)/src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
                                    <outputDirectory>META-INF</outputDirectory>
                                </fileSet>                                  
                            </fileSets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>
   </build>   
</project>
```

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

My Debug Configuration has the following list of goals:

> clean install axis2-aar:aar

From Eclipse, when I run a Maven Build from the Debug As context menu, the comes up when right clicking on the project, I get the aar into my target folder as indicated by the output below:

```
DEBUG] Exploding aar...
[DEBUG] Assembling aar axis2test in C:\Users\nji\workspace\axis2test\target\aar
[INFO] Generating aar C:\Users\nji\workspace\axis2test\target\axis2test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.aar
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\nji\workspace\axis2test\target\axis2test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.aar
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[DEBUG] adding directory com/
[DEBUG] adding directory com/pidac/
[DEBUG] adding directory com/pidac/axis2test/
[DEBUG] adding directory com/pidac/axis2test/api/
[DEBUG] adding directory com/pidac/axis2test/lib/
[DEBUG] adding entry com/pidac/axis2test/api/Hello.class
[DEBUG] adding entry com/pidac/axis2test/api/Weather.class
[DEBUG] adding entry com/pidac/axis2test/lib/HelloImpl.class
[DEBUG] adding entry com/pidac/axis2test/lib/WeatherService.class
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/maven/
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/maven/org.pidac.webservices/
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/maven/org.pidac.webservices/axis2test/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/maven/org.pidac.webservices/axis2test/pom.xml
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/maven/org.pidac.webservices/axis2test/pom.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, when I manually explode this AAR using 7-Zip, services.xml is not found anywhere.
The docs here [Maven2 AAR Plug-in Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-aar-plugin.html) says

> Location of the services.xml file. By default, it is assumed that the
>   file is already present in classesDirectory/META-INF and no special
>   processing is required

but when I look at the classesDirectory after the build is complete, there is no META-INF folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: First i assume that the goal is called aar instead of "axis2-aar:aar". Furthermore if you call mvn clean install the package lifecycle phase has already been run. An adding of axis2-aar:aar goal does not make sense. Just try simply mvn clean package and check the target folder.

Comment: Entering 'aar' as the goal within the Debug Configuration causes compile problems.  Entering this within POM, does nothing, so it looks like 'axis2-aar:aar' is what needs to be passed.  Changing the order of my goals to clean axis2-aar:aar install, again with Debug Configuration, does not change a thing besides not seeing output that aar is being exploded.  Interestingly enough services.xml is being added to .war.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to try more things and read between the lines:

Documentation here [Maven2 AAR Plug-in Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-aar-plugin.html) needs clarification on servicesXmlFile configuration parameter for this plugin and did not help me.  If you are lucky to get Intellisense when editing POM.xml within Eclipse, you will get a better description for this configuration parameter:

There should be three ways to fix this:

1. Create a folder META-INF under src/main/resources and add your services.xml.
2. Enter following configuration under  settings of project in POM.

   META-INF
           false
           ${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF
           
             services.xml
3. Enter path to services.xml in configuration settings for plugin, like so:

   org.apache.axis2
                   axis2-aar-maven-plugin
                   1.6.2
                   
                       
                           
                                axis2-aar:aar
                           
                           
                               ${baseDir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF
                               
                                   
                                        ${project.build.directory}/aar
                                        /

Probably caused by incorrect path, I could not get this alternative to work.  Maybe someone can comment.